# Correct syntax to combine xargs -i and sh -c?

Tags: shell, xargs

I have a file containing a list of null seperated filenames.
The output of 'xxd list' is:

```
00000000: 216d 706f 7373 6962 6c65 0022 4269 675f  !mpossible."Big_
00000010: 5369 7822 5f63 7269 636b 6574 5f64 6973  Six"_cricket_dis
00000020: 7075 7465 5f6f 665f 3139 3132 0022 446f  pute_of_1912."Do
00000030: 6322 5f53 6869 656c 7300 224a 7564 6765  c"_Shiels."Judge
00000040: 5f4a 7564 7922 5f53 6865 696e 646c 696e  _Judy"_Sheindlin
00000050: 0022 4a75 7374 5f79 6f75 725f 4176 6572  ."Just_your_Aver
00000060: 6167 655f 5365 636f 6e64 5f4f 6e5f 5468  age_Second_On_Th
00000070: 6973 5f50 6c61 6e65 7422 5f31 3939 372d  is_Planet"_1997-
00000080: 3139 3938 0022 4b69 6e67 225f 4a6f 655f  1998."King"_Joe_
00000090: 4f6c 6976 6572 0022 4d6f 7468 6572 225f  Oliver."Mother"_
000000a0: 456d 6d61 5f42 7563 6861 6e61 6e00 224e  Emma_Buchanan."N
000000b0: 6f6c 6c79 2200 2250 6570 7065 7222 5f50  olly"."Pepper"_P
000000c0: 6f74 7473 0022 536b 6970 7065 7222 2867  otts."Skipper"(g
000000d0: 616d 655f 6361 6e6e 6f6e 2900            ame_cannon).
```

When I run the command:

```
xargs -0 -a list -I{} sh -c "html2text -ascii -o ~/text/{} ./{}"
```

It produces the following errors:

```
Cannot open input file "./Doc_Shiels".
Cannot open input file "./Just_your_Average_Second_On_This_Planet_1997-1998".
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

What is the correct syntax to use, to get this to run properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you invoke `sh -c "...{}..."`, the embedded value is inserted as-is.

One of your original values is: `"Doc"_Shiels`

When you insert it into the command string that will be passed to the shell, you have:

```
html2text -ascii -o ~/text/{} ./{}
```

turning into:

```
html2text -ascii -o ~/text/"Doc"_Shiels ./"Doc"_Shiels
```

Because the double-quotes are not escaped, they effectively vanish.

Thus your error message.

---

It is possible to escape your input so that the shell handles it correctly but doing so is error-prone and best avoided.

Instead you can pass the values as arguments:

```
xargs -0 -a list -I{} \
    sh -c 'html2text -ascii -o ~/text/"$1" ./"$1"' -- {}
```

POSIX [tells us about `-c`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sh.html):

```
sh -c [-abCefhimnuvx] [-o option]... [+abCefhimnuvx] [+o option]...
       command_string [command_name [argument...]]
```

> `-c`
>
> Read commands from the command_string operand. Set the value of special parameter 0 (see Special Parameters) from the value of the command_name operand and the positional parameters ($1, $2, and so on) in sequence from the remaining argument operands. No commands shall be read from the standard input.

In my example, I have used `--` for `command_name` and `{}` as a single `argument`.

Within `command_string` the argument can be referred to as `$1`. I have changed the double-quotes to single-quotes so that `$1` is not converted too early (ie. not by the shell xargs is running under).